# Is there a way for me to help Clang Static Analyzer understand global constant objects?

Tags: c++, constants, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

Background:  because *reasons*, my code likes to return success/error-code values from its functions in the form of a (very lightweight) class-object.  This works fine, however I'm having some difficulty getting Clang Static Analyzer to understand what's going on; its confusion causes it to emit spurious "uninitialized-value" warnings when it analyzes my program.

Here's some minimal example code to illustrate/reproduce the (mis)behavior:

// my_status_t_class.h

```
#ifndef MY_STATUS_T_CLASS_H
#define MY_STATUS_T_CLASS_H

class status_t
{
public:
   status_t(int errorNumber) : _errorNumber(errorNumber) {/* empty */}

   bool IsError() const {return (_errorNumber != 0);}

private:
   int _errorNumber;
};

// A list of some common error codes
const status_t STATUS_NO_ERROR(0);
const status_t STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND(-1);
// [...]

#endif
```

// my_test_program.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "my_status_t_class.h"

status_t GetValue(int & ret) 
{
   if (rand()%2)
   {
      ret = 5;
      return STATUS_NO_ERROR;
   }
   else return STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int ret;
   if (GetValue(ret).IsError()) ret = 5;
   printf("ret=%i\n", ret);
   return 0;
}
```

When I run `scan-build` on the above code, it gives this output:

```
$ scan-build g++ -std=c++17 my_test_program.cpp
scan-build: Using '/Users/jaf/llvm-project/build/bin/clang-16' for static analysis
testhashtable.cpp:20:8: warning: 2nd function call argument is an uninitialized value [core.CallAndMessage]
   printf("ret=%i\n", ret);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

1 warning generated.

.... and it generates a report about the error which can be viewed at [this link](https://public.msli.com/lcs/jaf/scan-build-2022-11-13-204017-75554-1/index.html).

As you can see from the report, ClangSA seems to think that it is possble for my `GetValue()` function to return `STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND`, but then have the `IsError()` method return false inside `main()`, leaving the `ret` local-variable undefined when it is used.

In actuality, that isn't possible -- `IsError()` will return true, so then `main()` will execute `ret = 5;` and so `ret` will always have a well-defined value when I pass it in to `printf()`.

My question is, is this a bug in ClangSA?  Or if not, is there a recommended way for me to get ClangSA to understand/follow the semantics of my `status_t` class here?  (It seems like it should be able to, since the code is all defined in the `my_status_t_class.h` header file which ClangSA has direct access to).

I did notice that if I replace the constant-declarations in `my_status_t_class.h` with `#define` declarations instead, I get the behavior I want, e.g. if I do this:

// my_status_t_class.h

```
[...]

// A list of some common error codes
#define STATUS_NO_ERROR       status_t(0)
#define STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND status_t(-1)
// [...]
```

... then ClangSA doesn't produce the spurious warning... but of course that is quite an ugly solution, and I'd like to avoid it if there is a better alternative.

Comment: In my opinion, you're asking a heck of a lot from static analysis.  What you're asking almost requires simulated execution.

Comment: @TimRoberts It's true, I am.... OTOH the fact that it works as expected if I use a `#define` in the header (instead of an inline `const status_t`) suggests to me that ClangSA is capable of that level of analysis, if it really puts its mind to it :)

Comment: It is not why the analyzer is producing the message, but the constructor in the class should be `constexpr`. Otherwise there is no guarantee that the constants are actually constant-initialized and could result in initialization order issues if other dynamic initialization is used. So if it wasn't `main` the diagnostic would be somewhat warranted. But the analyzer doesn't seem to produce it for that reason.

Comment: @user17732522 I agree (and in fact the constructor *is* tagged `constexpr` in my real code, but I removed that from the example code since I was trying to simplify it as much as possible and I could still reproduce the fault without it... dunno if that was a good decision or not)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug in the static analyser ... *unless* you also get a "value unused" warning if you assign `ret` an initial value (i.e. `int ret = 42;` as the declaration). In that case, there is a paradox.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the analyzer is not able to see that the `STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND` object is always an error, so it can't be sure that `ret` will always be initialized.

The reason it can't see that is because the `STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND` object is not a constant expression, so the analyzer can't know its value at compile-time.

One way to fix this would be to make the `STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND` object a constant expression, by using a `constexpr` constructor:

```
class status_t
{
public:
   constexpr status_t(int errorNumber) : _errorNumber(errorNumber) {/* empty */}


constexpr status_t STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND(-1);
```

With that change, the analyzer should be able to see that `STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND` is always an error, and so it will know that `ret` will always be initialized.

Alternatively, you could make the `STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND` object a global variable instead of a constant object, and initialize it with a constant expression:

```
status_t STATUS_DATA_NOT_FOUND = status_t(-1);
```

Comment: It's a good hypothesis, but when I make the suggested changes, the spurious warning still appears.  :(

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm honestly not sure then, does give something to think for a while.....

Comment: FWIW I submitted a bug-report (at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58991 ) .... perhaps it will do some good.